circle moves too far through a collection of points
Long story short, I'm making a trench warfare game. Trench walls are represented by an array of points, and I need my game characters, using a circular colliders, to stop when they hit a point, and slide past the points until they have no where else to slide, or they expend the velocity/movement/push vector. It works exactly how I want it to, except for the darn edge cases where the circle is allowed through, which is unnacceptable for this game. When I either force the character move through a bottle-neck, or rub back and forth against a curved wall, the circle is let through. I'm guessing it's just a float precision error, but idk how else to fix that.
I've tried using the epsilon value in every value comparison there is in my code, but the problem still shows itself. I would expect it to perfectly stop at the first point it would collide with and for that point to never enter inside the circle, but as I said, it is allowed through when forcing the circle through a bottleneck or rubbing back and forth against an edge
public Vector2 StopAtValue(Vector2 start, Vector2 end, float radius, bool value)
{
    // Tracks the number of slides (iterations) during the calculation
    var slideCount = 0;

    // The current start and end points for each iteration
    var currentStart = start;
    var currentEnd = end;

    // Original delta (difference) between start and end points
    var ogDelta = currentEnd - currentStart;

    // Total magnitude of movement processed so far
    float totalMagnitude = 0;

    // Initial movement direction, normalized to a unit vector
    var direction = (end - start).normalized;

    // Loop to simulate sliding along obstacles until maxSlides is reached
    while (slideCount < maxSlides)
    {
        // Variables to track the closest collision point and related information
        float smallestDist = Mathf.Infinity;
        Vector2 closestCirclePos = currentEnd;
        Vector2 closestCollisionPoint = currentEnd;

        // Iterate through chunks to find potential collision points
        foreach (var chunk in ChunkManager.Manager.chunks)
        {
            if (chunk == null || chunk.map == null)
            {
                continue; // Skip null or invalid chunks
            }

            // Get points in the chunk that obstruct the capsule-shaped area
            var points = chunk.map.GetBitsObstructingTaperedCapsule(currentStart, radius, currentEnd, radius, value);

            // Process each obstruction point
            foreach (var point in points)
            {
                var pointDelta = point - currentStart;

                // Calculate the dot product to ensure the point is in the forward direction
                var collisionPointDot = Vector2.Dot(direction.normalized, pointDelta);
                if (collisionPointDot <= 0)
                    continue; // Skip points behind the starting position

                // Calculate the perpendicular distance to the collision point
                var b = radius;
                var c = Mathf.Abs(Vector2.Dot(Vector2.Perpendicular(direction), point - currentStart));
                var a = Mathf.Sqrt((b * b) - (c * c));

                // Determine the circle's collision position
                var circleStartDelta = (collisionPointDot - a) * direction;
                var circlePos = circleStartDelta + currentStart;

                // Update the closest collision point if this is the nearest so far
                var distance = circleStartDelta.magnitude;
                if (distance < smallestDist)
                {
                    if (drawCollisionTests)
                    {
                        GeoUtils.MarkPoint(point, bitWidth * 0.5f, new Color(0, 1, 0, 0.2f));
                    }

                    closestCirclePos = circlePos;
                    smallestDist = distance;
                    closestCollisionPoint = point;
                    continue;
                }

                // Optionally visualize points that are further away
                if (drawCollisionTests)
                {
                    GeoUtils.MarkPoint(point, bitWidth * 0.5f, new Color(1, 0, 0, 0.2f));
                }
            }
        }

        // Debug visuals for collision testing
        if (drawCollisionTests)
        {
            var transparentGreen = new Color(0, 1, 0, 1);
            Debug.DrawRay(currentStart, direction, Color.blue);
            GeoUtils.DrawCircle(currentStart, radius, Color.blue);
            GeoUtils.DrawCircle(closestCirclePos, radius, transparentGreen);
            GeoUtils.MarkPoint(closestCollisionPoint, bitWidth / 2, transparentGreen);
        }

        // If no collision was found, return the current end position
        if (smallestDist == Mathf.Infinity)
        {
            if (logWallSlides)
                Debug.Log($"{slideCount} slides");

            return currentEnd;
        }

        // Calculate the new direction based on the collision point
        totalMagnitude += (closestCirclePos - currentStart).magnitude;
        var collisionPointDelta = (closestCollisionPoint - closestCirclePos);
        var collisionDot = Vector2.Dot(Vector2.Perpendicular(direction), collisionPointDelta);

        direction = Vector2.Perpendicular(collisionPointDelta).normalized;
        if (-collisionDot < 0)
        {
            direction = -direction;
        }

        // Stop sliding if the direction is opposite to the original movement
        if (Vector2.Dot(ogDelta, direction) < 0)
        {
            if (logWallSlides)
                Debug.Log($"{slideCount} slides");

            return closestCirclePos;
        }

        // Apply friction and calculate the deflection direction
        var angleRatio = (1 - frictionAngleMod * (Vector2.Angle(ogDelta, direction) / 90)) * (1 - wallFriction);
        var magnitude = Mathf.Min(radius, (ogDelta.magnitude - totalMagnitude) * angleRatio);

        var deflectionDir = direction * magnitude;

        // Update the current start and end positions for the next iteration
        currentStart = closestCirclePos;
        currentEnd = currentStart + deflectionDir;

        // Increment the slide count
        slideCount++;
    }

    // Log the total number of slides if necessary
    if (logWallSlides)
        Debug.Log($"{slideCount} slides");

    return currentEnd;
}



"I would expect it to perfectly stop at the first point it would collide with and for that point to never enter inside the circle ..." That's what I do (with each "prediction" / extrapolation):  if rectangles, see if they "intersect"; if irregular polygons, see "if point in polygon". In your case, if "point in circle ..."

sorry what are you saying?

"Collision detection".

Man idk if you're saying something helpful or nonsense ofc it's collision detection?

Sorry. I assumed a particular background.
